# How would i handle errors when using jQuery.ajax()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

When using jQuery's AJAX method to submit form data, what is the best way to handle errors? This is an example of what a call might look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "userCreation.ashx",
    data: { u:userName, p:password, e:email },
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(){disableSubmitButton();},
    complete: function(){enableSubmitButton();},
    error: function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown){
            // Work out what the error was and display the appropriate message
        },
    success: function(data){
            displayUserCreatedMessage();
            refreshUserList();
        }
});
```

The request might fail for a number of reasons, such as duplicate user name, duplicate email address etc, and the `ashx` is written to throw an exception when this happens.

My problem seems to be that by throwing an exception the `ashx` causes the `statusText` and `errorThrown` to be undefined. I can get to the `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` which contains the HTML that makes up the standard .net error page.

I am finding the page title in the `responseText` and using the title to work out which error was thrown. Although I have a suspicion that this will fall apart when I enable custom error handling pages.

Should I be throwing the errors in the `ashx`, or should I be returning a status code as part of the data returned by the call to `userCreation.ashx`, then using this to decide what action to take? How do you handle these situations?

Comment: What about try catch throw and finally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're setting `Response.StatusCode` to something other than 200. Write your exception's message using `Response.Write`, then use...

```
xhr.responseText
```

in your javascript/ajax I hope this work.

Answer (score 0):

If the server does not do something it was kindly asked to do, then it makes more sense for the server to return an error code along a message.

For example, trying to create a new user with an existing user name could return an error such as:

> 409 Conflict: User Exists

When the server returns an HTTP code other than 200 to 299, or 304 (i.e. not modified), then your `error()` callback gets called. The `textStatus` should be set to `error` in that case.

The HTTP error code can be checked looking at the `status` field as in:

```
if(jqxhr.status == 409)
{
    // got a conflict (i.e. same username)
    ...
}
```

And as you mentioned in your answer, the `jqxhr.responseText` will include the error message (`"Conflict: User Exists"` in my example above.)